# "Code too large" in Android Studio when using exported sklearn model

Tags: java, android, scikit-learn

Currently I am trying to export a model from sklearn to Android. For this I use the library `sklearn-porter` ([sklearn-porter](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter)).

This generates a Java class from the trained model, which looks like the following:

```
class DecisionTreeClassifier {

   public static int predict(double[] features) {
        int[] classes = new int[2];

        if (features[350] <= 0.5156863033771515) {
            if (features[568] <= 0.0019607844296842813) {
                if (features[430] <= 0.0019607844296842813) {
                    if (features[405] <= 0.009803921915590763) {
...
}
```

This file has a size of about 1 MB and thus the error "Code too large" occurs in Android Studio.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: A single method in a Java class may be at most 64KB of bytecode. You are well over this. You should move this code into a database or a properties file somehow. You can then either read the database or read the properties file.

Comment: Can you explain with an example how you invoke the predict function from a properties file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute the porter with `export_data=True`then you also get a small java class which reads the DecisionTree parameters from a `.json` file:

```
porter = Porter(clf, language='java')
output = porter.export(export_data=True)
print(output)
```